# Laravel form input integer length

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel

In Laravel form input validation, you can specify a minimum and a maximum length of a given input field.

```
$inputRules = [
    'postCode' => 'min:3|max:8'
];
```

#### Validation outcome

- 'BA45TZ' = `true`
- 'FF'     = `false`
- 'GH22 55XYZ' = `false`

However if I do the same for a number, it will validate whether the input is less than or greater than the input, then return on that.

```
$inputRules = [
    'cv2' => 'min:3|max:4'
];
```

#### Validation outcome

- '586' = `false`
- '4'     = `true`
- '2' = `false`
- '3' = `true`

I actually want to validate a numbers *length* not it's numerical value. I can't figure out how to do this. Google has been no help, or I am not searching the right thing.

Anybody had any experience with this?

EDIT: I have answered my own question. I had missed Laravels `digits_between`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like an idiot, I missed Laravels `digits_between` validator rule. I swear I had scoured those rules, but here we are.

Thank you everyone for your help.

```
$inputRules = [
    'cv2' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:3,4'
];
```

Comment: Wow didn't know this one. So I guess I'm an idiot too :P Just note that you won't be able to use this for only min or max.

Comment: If you didn't know you can accept your own answer. However, you have to wait 48 hours to do so.

Answer (score 6):

That's the expected behavior of Laravel's `size`, `min` and `max` validations. You can't change it.

> For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.

To solve this you have to create a [custom validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules).
Something like this:

```
Validator::extend('min_length', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
    return strlen($value) >= $parameters[0];
});

Validator::extend('max_length', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
    return strlen($value) <= $parameters[0];
});
```

And you can use them in the same way:

```
'cv2' => 'min_length:3|max_length:4'
```

Comment: This is the exact thing I was looking for, I'll be damned if I could find this anywhere else. Thanks buddy.

Is there a preferred place to put this? I would rather not have it in the method that I am using to validate.

Comment: The preferred place to register this (especially in Laravel 5) would be a service provider.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I'm sorry, where should I put this code? I'm looking for best practices and this is what I was looking for

Comment: @ggderas As I said in my previous comment, this should go into a service provider. You can find a section about them in the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

For length in number you've to use size, but you can't put ranges in it. So, the best thing to do is making a custom validation.
Here is the documentation in laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules

And an example:

```
Validator::extend('minsize', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return  strlen($value) >= $parameters[0];
});
```

And do the same with maxsize.